# MATE 19.04 - panel objects losing position on log out

Tags: panel, ubuntu-mate

After system reboot, my panel objects are often, but not always, arbitrarily reordered. This happens only to custom objects and only to objects on the right half of the top panel. It happens even to 'locked' items.

Is this reordering a bug or have I missed a feature?

Comment: Please ask this question on https://ubuntu-mate.community/ to get more authoritative answer.